# Using update and select clause in one query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like below .

```
circle_user

user_id    circle_id     user_type_id
1            1              1
2            1              2
3            1              2
```

```
user_type
id    type
1     admin
2     member
```

I have to  implement **switch admin concept** . If a user deletes his account and leaves his circle , new admin must be assigned to that circle. for example in the given circle_user table if user_id = 1 deletes his account , than next member of that circle must become the admin of that circle. 
So i need a query which will select the very next member of that circle and update the user_type_id from 2 to  1 .

I need a result like.

```
circle_user

user_id    circle_id     user_type_id
1            1              1
2            1              1
3            1              2
```

How can i do this in one query? I have circle_id = 1 as Parameter .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are asking for. But just as the first iteration:

```
UPDATE circle_user
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MIN(user_id) circle_id
    FROM circle_user 
    GROUP BY circle_id
    HAVING SUM(IF(user_type_id=1,1,0))=0
  ) cu
  ON circle_user.circle_id = cu.circle_id
SET circle_user.user_type_id = 1
```